# Send message to all users (Internal table)

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables Users and Inbox.

I am trying to get all users and create a record from each in another table.

This is what I'm trying but it's not right:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM `users`"); //Get all the users

    while (($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) != false) {

        $sql = "INSERT INTO inbox VALUES ('id goes here keeping empty','user id goes here','sender user id goes here','message title here','This is the message','date goes here')"; //Send message to them all

}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: use `VALUES`, not `VALUE`

Comment: @haim770 is right. Also I would suggest using PDO's, instead, as it' s safer. http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php

Comment: also - just spotted this - '!==' is not valid. It's supposed to be '!='

Comment: [`!==`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) is valid **and in fact recommended**, as well as [`VALUE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html) when inserting one single row.

Comment: You are not running the second query at all.

Comment: @Pekka웃 Could you please explain why? I cannot see the reason.

Comment: @RandomSeed `$sql = '...'` does not run a database query, does it?

Comment: `$sql = "INSERT INTO inbox VALUES ('id goes here keeping empty','user id goes here','sender user id goes here','message title here','This is the message','date goes here')"; //Send message to them all
`, where is $sql used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this insertion in one single query, and without the need to transfer any data from your database to PHP:

```
INSERT INTO inbox
SELECT NULL, users.id, @sender, @title, @message, @date
FROM users
```